# Images links with twig

Tags: symfony, twig

is there a way to get an image by using the twig concatenation method, like this :

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/Achievements/" ~ ach.id ~".png') }}">
```

Every picture in my pic folder is named after the id of her achievement, and can be accessed by using "ach.id".

I tried this way, but it doesn't work. I'm pretty sure I have to use ~ to concatenate, but I don't know if twig handles the link + concatenation thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your inverted commas.

Try this instead:

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/Achievements/'~ach.id~'.png') }}">
```

Comment: No problem. If it solved your problem, you can choose this answer as solution.